# CSS not working while checking preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preview

1) I have a form and I am displaying a preview of that form in the next tab. I set some CSS but after click on the preview button, CSS is not reflecting on the fields.

2) Is there any other way to display the tab in new tab instated of the opening window?

```js
/*form preview*/
function PrintPreview() {
  var toPrint = document.getElementById('from_privew');
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=1000,location=no,left=200px');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::Print Preview::</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="screen"/></head><body>')
  popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
  popupWin.document.write('</div></body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

```css
@media print{
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="email"] {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 05px;
      border-radius: 05px;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    a {
      background: #0088cc;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 05px;
      padding: 08px 25px;
      color: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="from_privew">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    <a href="#" onclick="PrintPreview()">Preview</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of a new window you can use an iframe.

Comment: You are using `@media print` in your css, it will be visible/applied only while printing or printing preview. Opening new window is not print preview. Try to open your print preview in Chrom and press `Ctrl+P` and you will see your css rules.

Comment: @xxxmatko, I just want to display in the next tab. Iframe will display like user want to take a print a form

Comment: Print preview is feature of the browser. You can call `window.print()` which will trigger print in the browser (in Chrome for instance you will be able to see the resulting html with css media print applied)

Comment: If you want to open new tab and let the user see the print result, just remove `@media print` from your css.

Comment: @xxxmatko, I think there is some miss communication between us. You know WordPress If any admin update any thing in admin panel but before he wants to check the preview then will click the preview tab and next tab will open with the latest update.

Comment: Check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEgWYd

Comment: Yes, CSS is working because you add CSS in the script but that will work only for preview. I need both. I mean in HTML also and in Preview also

Comment: So what are you trying to do? After clicking the preview button, open new tab with the same html, and css applied in the old tab and also the new tab?

Comment: @xxxmatko, After research, I got some info that media print will display the CSS. So I added all my style in that but that is not working.If I remove it from my CSS then it will work but not in preview.

Comment: And your code suggests me to add all CSS in the script. I just use single CSS and that will reflect my HTML and Preview both

Comment: Just use your css file instead of the inline css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154105/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-xxxmatko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your css in separated file `Print.css` and remove the `@media print`:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 05px;
    border-radius: 05px;
}

input[type="submit"],
a {
    background: #0088cc;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 05px;
    padding: 08px 25px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then modify your javascript to include reference for this file:

```
function PrintPreview() {
    var toPrint = document.getElementById('from_privew');
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=1000,location=no,left=200px');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('\
        <html> \
            <head> \
                <title>::Print Preview::</title> \
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="screen"/> \
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"> \
            </head> \
            <body> \
                <div>')
    popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
    popupWin.document.write('\
                </div> \
            </body> \
        </html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

For the second part, whether the page is open in a new window or a new tab depends on browser (or browser settings). So I think you can not do much about this.

Comment: I found the second resolution also, I have to delete in the script  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=1000,location=no,left=200px'); and added  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');